# CUDA: fastest way reading display buffer?

Tags: cuda, buffer, screenshot, framebuffer

What's the fastest way to read the screen buffer using CUDA (**Whole** screen, not just a window)?
Can I do this without copying tons of pixels between host and device?
 Can I access this specific buffer directly?

Comment: I don't believe there is *any* way of reading the screen buffer using CUDA.

Comment: I'm a newbie. Can u give me more explanation on this? What can CUDA do? Do I need to access the VGA mem?

Comment: Alter the gl buffer before being sent to display buffer. GL interop.

Answer (score 2):

Render to an openGL render buffer object, then use [CUDA OpenGL interop](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL) to map it to a device pointer and read it in a CUDA kernel. You can also do the equivalent with [Direct3D](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__D3D11).

See the [Graphics Samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#graphics) included with the CUDA SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is how can I map the render buffer for the ENTIRE screen( without copying buffer to host mem )? For example, how can I catch a screenshot including start menu, desktop icons things?

Comment: That is not a CUDA question, and is not what you originally asked. You should post that as a separate question or remove the CUDA tag. A quick google turned up [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/03/25/ways-to-capture-the-screen.aspx).  If my answer was helpful, please upvote and/or accept.